# Kernel-level pass-through method to change file hashes

Tags: linux, encryption, hashing, md5, loopback

I'm searching for any kernel-level mechanism that is pass-through and will change file hashes by either encrypting file contents or appending data. The most obvious solution is encryption, but I can't find any appropriate (e.g. fully kernel-only, no ecryptfs, nothing FUSE powered, etc) encryption methods.

Specifically, I have a large number of files in `/foo` that I would like to also appear in `/foobar` in any manner that obfuscates the original MD5 of the files, **without** duplicating the raw data. I'm not concerned if the files in `/foobar` are rendered useless by additions--I'm happy to append a few random bytes to each file and let that break many of file formats, but I don't know how to do this with some sort of bind mount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a custom filesystem overlay, FUSE is the right direction. There are various custom filesystems written using FUSE (sshfs, ntfs-3g, wikipediafs...), including simple overlays like [bindfs](http://bindfs.org/).

One could take the bindfs source code and modify it to, say, XOR the first byte with some random data whenever it processes a read operation.

For a pure kernel option, you could modify `overlayfs` or `unionfs` drivers in a similar way.

Another alternative is to take Samba, write a Samba vfs module to corrupt files, share the source directory, and mount it on the same machine using the Linux `cifs` driver. (The same is also possible using the `9p` driver and the `u9fs` daemon, or with the `nfs` driver and some-or-other NFS server daemon.)

---

If you don't care about the contents, create sparse files with the desired size; they'll occupy no space at all:

```
$ truncate -s 1G largefile
$ du -h --apparent largefile
1G  largefile
$ du -h largefile
0   largefile
```

Loop over a tree like this:

```
cd /foo
find -type d | while read -r file; do
    mkdir -p "/foobar/$file"
done
find -type f | while read -r file; do
    truncate -r "$file" "/foobar/$file"
done
```

Comment: I need a kernel-level mechanism, which rules out any use of FUSE :-/ Otherwise this would be great :-P

Comment: Oh, sparse files is a great idea, but I should clarify that I *do* care about the contents being preserved, I just want the hash different. I'll update my post, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Hamy: Could you also explain _why_ is a kernel-level mechanism required specifically, and what makes FUSE unusable?

Comment: Sure - kernel-only is a requirement of CrashPlan - It apparently cannot properly stat files (such as encrypted files) unless the modifications are done in the kernel and are therefore totally invisible to it. The kernel-only requirement removes the ability to use FUSE entirely because (AFAIK) every single FUSE-based filesystem is executed in userspace while fuse itself is the part run in the kernel

Comment: FYI, I have not tried a FUSE-based system yet, but I see hopeful reports that sshfs can indeed be used with crashplan at http://askubuntu.com/questions/337305/back-up-sshfs-network-drive-to-crashplan, so I am giving it a shot right now. Perhaps the answer has been obvious all along...*fingers crossed*

Comment: @Hamy: The FUSE "controller" is in the user space, but the filesystem driver is in-kernel, and assuming the controller implements the necessary functions, it is _indistinguishable_ from any other filesystem to all other user-space programs. And as the Ask Ubuntu post shows, the problem isn't FUSE being half-userspace but rather FUSE by default denying access to other users than the mounter (`-o allow_other`).

Comment: You are correct, I misunderstood what CrashPlan meant by "kernel-only" when ecryptfs didn't work out of the box. Just tested a FUSE-based filesystem and it worked perfectly, so thanks a ton for getting me to give FUSE a second look!